# Not able to update src in <embed>

Tags: 2010, javascript, content-editor-web-part

I used the below code in content editor to extract the query string and update the src of `<embed>`.

```
<object><embed id="ExampleEmbed" src="somfile" height="850" width="850" 
type="application/pdf"></embed></object>

  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     function getParameterByName(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

    var qsValue = getParameterByName("pdf");
alert(qsValue);
    if (qsValue)
    {
      alert("Inside");
        var game=document.getElementById("ExampleEmbed");
   alert(game);
  var clone=game.cloneNode(true);
   alert(clone);
  clone.setAttribute("src",qsValue);
  game.parentNode.replaceChild(clone,game);
    }</script>
```

The query string name is "pdf". Everything is working fine except when the javascript code replaces the original `<embed>` with new `<embed>` it is not displaying anything inside the content editor. Please help me find the problem.

Comment: Instead of cloning have you tried game.setAttribute("src",qsValue); ?

Comment: @AmalHashim Now it is not able to change the src. The same pdf is getting displayed

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a limitation of `embed` tag. You can use an `iframe` instead

```
<iframe id="ExampleEmbed" src="somfile" height="850" width="850"></iframe>

<script>
function ChangeSrc(qsValue) {
    document.getElementById("ExampleEmbed").src=qsValue;
}
</script>
```

**Update**

```
<div id="embedDiv">
    <object>
        <embed id="ExampleEmbed" src="somfile" height="850" width="850" type="application/pdf">
        </embed>
    </object>
</div>

function UpdateEmbedSrc(newSrc) {
    var div = document.getElementById("embedDiv");
    div.innerHTML('<object><embed id="ExampleEmbed" src="' + newSrc + '" height="850" width="850" type="application/pdf"></embed></object>');
}
```

Comment: iframe is not able to render the pages of pdf. Instead it is asking if I want to download the file as soon as  I save my content editor web part changes

Comment: Try updated answer

Comment: It seems that this line     div.innerHTML('<object><embed id="ExampleEmbed" src="' + newSrc + '" height="850" width="850" type="application/pdf"></embed></object>');
} has some problem. Because when I put alert() after this line the alert dialog box is not popping up